# How to make ant console always visible in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ant

When I have to see ant console every time I do "widow -> show view -> ant". And when the eclipse is restarted the ant console is hidden I need to do the same process again to see the ant window, is there any way that ant console is always open by default ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the ant console showing you can save your perspective so you will see it every time eclipse is started. http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-43e.htm

Comment: this worked just fine, but isn't there any option like to add view onload ?